# How do I change the color of the clicked button in my menu bar?

Tags: wordpress, colors

[image]

I need some help changing the color of the clicked menu button! Ive looked everywhere for an answser on wordpress, and now I am looking to the internet! As you can see from the picture, the colors are black and orange, and the blue does not go with that. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS element state (Active, and Visited) to specify the color needed.

```
a:visited, a:active {
color: red;
}
```

You can change the 'a' with the element class. You can send me your website URL and I will prepare the right code for you.

Thanks, let me know if I can help.

Comment: I apologie is the code is a bit hard for you to understand. Just send me your website URL and I will prepare the exact code for you.

Comment: Hi! My site isnt published yet, it is sitting on a "coming soon" page. I was just looking to change that blue color to white. Not sure what I can do to change that!

Comment: Hi,
Check these  pages to help you edit the color for those links:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp